# Store my "Sybase" query result /output into a script variable

Tags: sql, bash, scripting, sybase

I need a variable to keep the results retrieved from a query (Sybase) that´s in a script.

I have built the following script, it works fine I get the desired result when I run it
Script: **EXECUTE_DAILY:**

```
isql -U database_dba -P password <<EOF!
select the_name from table_name where m_num="NUMB912" and date="17/01/2019"
go
quit
EOF!
echo "All Done"
```

Output:

```
"EXECUTE_DAILY" 97 lines, 293 characters
user@zp01$ ./EXECUTE_DAILY
 the_name
 -----------------------------------
 NAME912

(1 row affected)
```

But now I would like to keep the output`(the_name: NAME912)` in a variable.

So far this is basically what I'm trying with no success.

```
variable=$(isql -U database_dba -P password -se "select the_name from table_name where m_num="NUMB912" and date="17/01/2019" ")
```

But, is not working. I can't save **NAME912** in a variable.

Comment: what **is** being stored in the variable?

Comment: hi @markp like keep the result saved  then I can *reuse* it in a different part of the script *calling* the variable (or the equivalent, I don't know if variable is the correct terminology)

Comment: my question was geared more towards what does `echo $variable` show you has been stored in your variable?  this should give you an idea of what's wrong with this particular approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the output for the desired string/piece-of-data that you wish to store in your variable.  I tend to make my life a bit easier by making sure I can easily/quickly search/parse out what I want.

Keeping a few issues in mind ...

- I tend to use `isql -s"|" -w10000` to ensure (most of the time) that a) the result set has all columns delimited with the pipe ('|') and b) a single row of data does not span multiple rows; the pipe delimiter makes it easier to parse out columns that may contain white space; obviously (?) use a different delimiter if a pipe may be part of your actual data
- to make parsing of the `isql` output a bit easier I tend to add a unique, grep-able (literal) string to the rows that I'm looking to search/parse
- some databases (eg, SQLAnywhere, Oracle) tend to mimic a literal value as the column header if said literal string has not been assigned an explicit alias/header; this means that if you do a simple search on your literal string then you'll get a match for the result set header as well as the actual data row
- I tend to capture all `isql` output to a temporary file; this allows for easier follow-on processing, eg, error checking, data parsing, dumping contents to a logfile, etc

So, with the above in mind my code typically looks something like:

```
$ outfile=/tmp/.$$.isql.outfile

$ isql -s"|" -w10000 -U database_dba -P password <<-EOF > ${outfile} 2>&1

-- 'GREP'||'ME' ensures that 'GREPME' only shows up in the data row

select 'GREP'||'ME',the_name
from   table_name
where  m_num = "NUMB912"
and    date  = "17/01/2019"
go
EOF

$ cat ${outfile}
... snip ...
|'GREP'||'ME'|the_name  |    # notice the default column header = 'GREP'||'ME' which won't match my search for 'GREPME'
|------------|----------|
|GREPME      |NAME912   |    # this is the line I want to search/parse
... snip ...

$ read -r namevar < <(egrep GREPME ${outfile} | awk -F"|" '{print $3}')
$ echo ${namevar}
NAME912
```